# Statistical significance in context of time series data?

Tags: regression, time-series, inference, p-value

I understand statistical significance in the general sense: we take a sample from a population and compute some parameter from the sample to infer what is the propulsion parameter to some degree of confidence, usually 95%. So if I want to find the p-value for a slope between two financial datasets, say interest rates each quarter, then I’d compute the slope between the two sample datasets and find the p-value. Less than 5%, we conclude the slope arrived at is very unlikely to have occurred by random chance. Otherwise, we fail to reject the hypothesis that the population slope is 0.

Here’s my question… if we are dealing with 200 quarters of data, what exactly is our “population?” In the commonly used example of IQs, the population is easily defined as the IQs of ALL the people. With financial data, considering quarterly data, it isn’t clear to me what is the population. Is it all historical data dating back to as long as our interest rates, in our example, existed? So if there were actually 500 quarters where our interest rates existed, that’s the population of data? Is it all of the data measured more granularly? Our interest rate measured at every second, millisecond, etc.?

I’m asking because I’m a bit perplexed how a p-value can be interpreted if we find the p-value for a slope between two datasets of interest rates, both 200 quarters worth of data. The sampling distribution which is assumed to be normal makes sense when thinking of pulling a sample of IQs from the population of all IQs.. how does it work for pulling sample last from the population of our interest rate data?

Additionally and most importantly, the reason I’m interested in this is because I am calculating the rolling slopes 24 quarters at a time, moving by one quarter at a time. If I run a t test on each slope, most are highly insignificant. If I think of these slopes as not trying to ascertain the population slope, but as simply representing the sample slope, then I think the idea of significance goes out the window here. Right? Confusing!

Sorry for the long winded question… I want to be as clear as possible where I’m confused. As always thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

It's a great question.  The biggest problem, as I see it, is the (over-)use of the term "population."  It really does not mean "population" in nearly every statistical context, even in the IQ case you mention. In fact, authors often put "population" in quotes ("") to underscore that they do not really mean population in the strict sense.

Instead, there is a *data generating process* (DGP) by which the data elements are produced. In time series this makes perfect sense: As you mention there is no population.  On the other hand, there are potentially observable data at every single time point that *were not observed*. To understand this clearly, just put yourself back in time before a particular data point was observed.  If you knew what that data value would be, you would not use a statistical model.  But you probably did not know what that data point would be, so instead you assume that it comes from some probabilistic process, which you model using ARIMA, GARCH, or whatever probabilistic model is appropriate.

So in the context of time series data, the target of all statistical inference is the data generating process. You choose a model for it (ARIMA, GARCH etc.), and the validity of the methods hinges upon the validity of your chosen model as a faithful representation of nature's process.

It is really no different in other fields like IQ measurements, or more generally, in cross sectional data.  It is nearly impossible that the pristine data collection requirements (perfect random sampling, instantaneous identical measurements, no nonresponse, etc.) needed for the "population" interpretation to hold actually do hold, so while the desired target of inference may well be some population, the data instead target the data generating process.

In regression, the necessity of the DGP point of view (rather than the population point of view) becomes even clearer, no matter whether time series or cross section.   Say you wish the population to be "everyone on Earth," and you want to predict IQ using height, weight, date of birth, gender, income, etc.  When you fix all the $X$ variables at some specified values, there may be only one person on the planet having those precise characteristics. So from the population point of view, the conditional distributions which are part of the true regression model are comprised of but a single number. Hardly what one would like for a "population"!  Usually populations are considered to be a large collection of numbers.

Even there is a "population" lurking around, scientists are usually more interested in something bigger than that. For example, biologists are usually more interested in how genetic processes govern human life, rather than in how many of which gene variants are present on Earth at any given point in time.  Thus, they would be interested in describing how the population data came to be the way it is, rather than in just the population. This requires the viewpoint that the population data themselves are the result of processes.

Bottom Line:
Just replace "population" with "data generating process" and everything will work out fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer here it helps immensely. Would you mind answering the second to last paragraph as well? My dilemma is I calculated the rolling correlations for 25 quarter periods but almost every r value in each 25 quarter period is insignificant. Even thought each r is insignificant, don’t they still tell something that actually happened in the data? For example, if in one 25 quarter period the r was 100%, it means in that particular window my two variables moved together perfectly. Right?

Comment: You couldn't blame lack of significance on the population issue.  Look to the usual suspects - small sample size, multicollinearity - anything that would make standard errors larger.  Or maybe there is some flaw in your analysis.